# How do i set the path of libhdfs.so for pyarrow?

Tags: pyarrow, libhdfs, python-hdfs

I'm trying to use pyarrow and i keep getting the following error.

```
ImportError: Can not find the shared library: libhdfs3.so
```

so i read some stackoverflow and it says that i need to set enviorment variable for ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR.
The path to libhdfs.so is /usr/local/hadoop/native/
it tried to set it in bashrc but it didn't work
the conda installation doesn't seem to work i.e.

```
conda install libhdfs3
pip install libhdfs3
conda install -c clinicalgraphics libgcrypt11
conda install libprotobuf=2.5
conda update libhdfs3
```

it will be a great help if i get this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ensure `libhdfs.so` is in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native` as well as in `$ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR`

use this to check if you have the variable set in your bash environment `ls $ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR`

if not locate the file using
`locate -l 1 libhdfs.so`

Assign the directory path you locate to the ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR variable using
`ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR=<directory location to libhdfs.so>`

referenced here in SO - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749351/6263217

Comment: Where is ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR supposed to be? Do i need to set it up?

Comment: It's a env variable.